# Can we preload texture / image in Threejs to avoid waiting during the render?

Tags: canvas, three.js, 3d, rendering, textures

I'm currently working on a feature where I want to display texture changes of an object over time.
To do that, I use a timeline. When the user clicks on a specific point, it loads the new values attached to the object (size, texture, color, etc...).

[image]

Problem is that it takes a bit more than a second to load the changes.
Is there a way to load the data immediately on change? For example, preload the texture images ?
Here's how I load my texture :

```
    let planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
    {
       map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(require("../../public/img/fondplan/" + floorFileName + ".jpg"), 
    () => { renderer.render(scene, this.camera); }),
       side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider to load all textures during the application start. You can show a loading screen in the meanwhile.

Use a single instance of `TextureLoader` for loading all assets and don't forget to create the loader with an instance of `LoadingManager`. The manager provides an `onLoad()` callback that you can use to detect the completion of the loading process.

Additionally, use [WebGLRenderer.initTexture()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.initTexture) after your textures have been loaded to minimize the overhead when the textures are used for the first time.